# knockout textbox validation error

Tags: knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

i am facing problem with knockout basic textbox validation

Here is my html

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:text" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" data-bind="click:save" value="save" />
```

Here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        ko.validation.registerExtenders();

        ko.validation.configure({
            registerExtenders: true,
            decorateElement: true
        });

        var vm = ko.validatedObservable({

            text: ko.observable().extend({
                required: true
            }),
            save: function () {
                debugger;
                if (this.isValid()) {
                    alert('success');
                }
                else {
                    this.errors.showAllMessages();
                    alert('error');
                }
            }
        });
        ko.applyBindings(vm);

    });
```

I have included below scripts

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.validation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

when i run this i am getting 'Undefined is not a function' at "this.isValid()"

Please help me.

Comment: You should start of by saying var self = this; when initializing your vm to avoid confusion. The error you get it because he doesn't find the isValid() for this. Try changing it to self. If that doesn't work, check if all of your scripts are in fact included correctly.

Comment: i have added var self = this in Save function and checked scripts but same error occur,.. please help me.

Comment: You misunderstood. You should add var self = this; as the first statement after var vm = ko.validatedObservable({. Then change the if(this.isValid()) to if(self.isValid()) and check again.

Comment: it is not allowing to place var self=this as first statement after var vm = ko.validatedObservable({... 'unexpected identifier' error getting... please provide me JSFiddle if possible

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this pattern to use validatedObservable - http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/PwNbEL

```
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

ko.validation.configure({
  registerExtenders: true,
  decorateElement: true
});

var vm = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.text= ko.observable().extend({
    required: true
  }),
  self.save= function () {
    if (this.isValid()) {
      alert('success');
    }
    else {
      this.errors.showAllMessages();
      alert('error');
    }
  }
};
var viewmodel = ko.validatedObservable(new vm())();
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```